# Apache Derby DB network server not starting

Tags: unix, derby

I want to run Derby DB in network server mode. I've configured with instruction presented in manual. According to this I'm supposed to start it with command

```
startNetworkServer
```

and expect at least output in console like this

```
Security manager installed using the Basic server security policy. Apache Derby Network Server - 10.4.1.3 - (648739) started and ready to accept connections on port 1527 at 2008-04-30 09:35:55.871 GMT
```

but nothing like this is printed (just new link). Of course trying to connect to it later gives error 08001 - connection refused.

Comment: What actually *is* printed? Can you enable "echo" for the script and run it, and share that output?

Comment: Actually nothing is printed, just new line. What do you mean by enabling "echo"? Putting extra flag or argument to executed command, or editing script? FYI: it worked when I've started it with flag `-noSecurityManager`.

Comment: The precise security error is to be found in your `derby.log` file. Glad you found a workaround, though it would be better to configure your security policy appropriately, which would depend on the precise flags and arguments you are giving to `startNetworkServer`, etc.